# Aptana Studio and xampp on Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, aptana-studio

I'm using Fedora and Aptana Studio 3. I can launch Aptana Studio and it works without 
problems. I can also type in localhost in the URL of my browser and it gives me the xampp-splash screen.

Now I'm setting up both to work together, So I used this tutorial
http://dev.tiki.org/XAMPP-Aptana#Set_Workspace.
It says for Linux: `/opt/lampp/htdocs`

When I type this in or navigate to this location (it exists) Aptana tells me:

> Could not launch the product because the specified workspace cannot be created. The specified workspace directory is either invalid or read-only.

How can I fix it, to work together?

If it helps: When I do

```
tar xvfz xampp-linux-1.8.1.tar.gz
```

in the terminal the folder is locked somehow and the properties tell me that root is the owner and not me. When I copy it with root into the folder, xampp tells me

```
Access denied
German standard text
Error 403
```

Comment: Did you do this: "For Linux and Mac, you'll probably need to adjust the permissions for the htdocs folder and the items in that folder in order for Aptana to be able to work with it. Grant full read and write permissions to all users and everyone." as described on the page you linked to?

Comment: Yes, I've done this already @terdon, but then I get a error message because of a new security concept of xampp. I didn't had those problems under windows, I switched to fedora just today.

Comment: How did you change the permissions? Did you run this command as root: `chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs`?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I did chmod -R 777 for /opt/lampp. So every folder in lampp